# Adding values in Dropdown list when i enter something in Textbox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I hope u will help me to find the answer.
here i have one TextBox and one DropDown list ok. In this, Example: If i enter "Anu" in textbox, it should load it in dropdown list according to the textbox text.
So how do i do? I am Using vb.net

Comment: You could call the keypress-event of the textbox and check for the keycode of 'Enter'. When pressed then add the value to the combobox?

Comment: Yes... its like that only... if i enter text like "Enter" it should load all like "Enter", "entff" in dropdown list.. related E letter.. 
@svranken

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" clientidmode="static" runat="server" onblur="AddItem();"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName" clientidmode="static" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function AddItem()

    {

        // Create an Option object        

        var opt = document.createElement("option");

      // Add an Option object to Drop Down/List Box

        document.getElementById("ddlName").options.add(opt);

        // Assign text and value to Option object

        opt.text = document.getElementById("txtName").value;

        opt.value = document.getElementById("txtName").value;

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Edited Please check ow

Comment: @Shu it should now as it is working on my end. Please share your code.

Comment: No its not working.....for example, if i enter c letter in text box i does't list all word  which start with the letter c in dropdown list.. even i dint write any code in code behind for that.. @Pawan

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop a Dropdownlist onto your page, with a button beside it.
Then double click the button and say:

```
Dropdownlist.Items.Add(Textbox1.Text);
```

PS: You'd better give us what you think about to avoid asking directly, because this will be misunderstood as homework.

Comment: he needs the javascript solution.

Comment: Any solutions?  Please check my above comments and give the solutions if u have.. @Pawan